# vmwarevm does not exist

Tags: vmware-fusion

.Trash/Windows XP Home Edition copy. - vmwarevm does not exist. What happen to my file? I tried to restore my Mac to a previous date and to no avail. If I reinstall Windows XP will I loose all of my software that I had on my Windows side?

Answer (score 0):

VMWare is looking for a VM in your trash folder. Did you empty your trash recently?